# Is there a way to disable typing/pasting into the date input and only allowing users to select from the date picker in AntD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

Is there a way to disable typing/pasting into the date input and only allowing users to select from the date picker in AntD? disabling doesn't work either. I've gone through the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) I tried this way

```
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';

...

handleDateChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}

...

render() {
  ...
  <DatePicker onChange={this.handleDateChange} ... />
  ...
}
```

This way it just stopped taking input values even through picker panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [antd date picker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/), you need to set `dispaly: none` in `ant-calendar-input-wrap` class.

[image: antd-datepicker]

**styles.css**. (You just only need to add this css in your `.css` file)

```
.ant-calendar-input-wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

**App.js**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <DatePicker  />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

please try with below prop

```
inputReadOnly={true}
```